# Modal Pop Up on top of panorama control

Tags: windows-phone-7, modal-dialog, panorama-control

A simple question:

My application first page is a panorama page. I want to show a modal pop up if user click on a button.

Can I show a modal pop up on top of panorama control?

By the way, How can I show a modal pop up?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of options:

1. Use the `Popup` control.
2. Use regular visual elements to construct your own dialog and show/hide accordingly.
3. Use a third party library such as the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) that includes controls that provide this functionality (such as `InputPrompt`, `MessagePrompt` or `PasswordPrompt`).

Personally, I'd go with either 2 or 3, because 1 has issues with handling orientation changes and performance issues that won't be fixed until the Mango release at the earliest.

Comment: I have a user control that I'm going to add to a Popup. Is this a visual element of point 2.

Comment: If using a Panorama Control I wouldn't worry about orientation changes. THe Panorama is only intended to be used in Portrait.

Comment: Good point Matt :) Point 2 was about using something other than Popup to remove it from the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean modal as in a child window, then what you can do is create a canvas that becomes visible when the user clicks on a button. It really is quite an easy solution, but if I have not answered the way you wish let me know, also, there is a great video tutorial site that the XNA website uses: http://channel9.msdn.com/series/windows-phone-7-development-for-absolute-beginners

Comment: I mean modal as a blocking dialog. If I'm showing that dialog, user can't interact with panorama control.

Comment: Instead of a canvas, I have a custom user control.

Comment: Im guessing that you have already tried to add the modal to the panorama control? If so, did you add it to one of the item's grid?

and if you already have the modal up, and the user can interact with the panorama control, but you don't want them to. Make your custom control the size of the screen, but then make it transparent minus what you want to show. just so that your custom control catches actions instead of the panorama control